# Can Java serialization be used with Gemfire/Geode, without deploying classes on the server?

Tags: gemfire, geode

The goal is to avoid having to deploy java classes to Gemfire/Geode servers.

The use-case only requires storage/retrieval of serialized objects.  The keys would be Strings.  There would be no use of server-side functions or OQL.

I'm aware that [Gemfire/Geode PDX](https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/geode/developing/data_serialization/gemfire_pdx_serialization.html) doesn't (in most cases) require java classes to be deployed to the Gemfire/Geode server.  I'm curious what is possible when using plain old Java serialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as there is no server side logic that will require deserializing the values, then I think it should work. Besides not using functions and OQL, and CacheListeners or CacheWriters would also require deserializing values on the server.

Comment: Thanks for confirming the idea Dan.  To clarify, I'm also wondering if anyone is doing this in a production environment.